# if rebinding doesn’t mutate the existing memory location of a variable, how do i get the old value after a rebind. forexample:

Tags: erlang, elixir

```
cat_poop = 12
> 12
```

if i rebind `cat_poop` to a new value forexample:

```
cat_poop = 20
> 20
```

So how do i get the first value of `cat_poop` after a rebind

Comment: That is impossible.

Comment: First about the syntax error: cat_poop there is not a variable but an atom because it starts with a lower case letter. So the first assignment will fail because cat_poop /= 12. Second, you typically cannot rebind any variable like that. The second assignment will fail because you have already said that cat_poop = 12, and because of the immutability in Erlang, you cannot say afterwards that cat_poop = 20 because 12 does not equal to 20.

Comment: why? you write your code knowing about the consequences of rebinding.  In the terminal you could (up-arrow) step back through the command-history and find your original assignment line and repeat it.

Comment: @dvaergiller This is Elixir, so your comment is incorrect. Variable names start with lower case, and rebinding is allowed.

Comment: @WojtekSurowka tags say it’s [tag:erlang], [tag:elixir] and nothing in the code tells it’s _Elixir_. So _your_ comment is incorrect and the one given by dvaergiller is ½-correct :)

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin I think that quite a hint towards Elixir is that cp = 12 has in the question value 12 :)

Answer (score 3):

You cannot get the previous value after an Elixir variable is rebound.